# How to keep the index when using pd.melt and merge to create a DataFrame for Seaborn and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I am trying to draw subplots using two identical DataFrames ( predicted and observed) with exact same structure ... the first column is index

The code below makes new index when they are concatenated using pd.melt and merge
as you can see in the figure the index of orange line is changed from 1-5 to 6-10

I was wondering if some could fix the code below to keep the same index for the orange line:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

actual = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 2],
                       'b': [89, 22, 44, 6, 44, 1]})
predicted = pd.DataFrame({'a': [7, 2, 13, 18, 20, 2],
                       'b': [9, 20, 4, 16, 40, 11]})

# Creating a tidy-dataframe to input under seaborn
merged = pd.concat([pd.melt(actual), pd.melt(predicted)]).reset_index()
merged['category'] = ''
merged.loc[:len(actual)*2,'category'] = 'actual'
merged.loc[len(actual)*2:,'category'] = 'predicted'

g = sns.FacetGrid(merged, col="category", hue="variable")
g.map(plt.plot, "index", "value", alpha=.7)
g.add_legend();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange line (`'variable' == 'b'`) doesn't have an index of `0-5` because of how you used `melt`. If you look at `pd.melt(actual)`, the index doesn't match what you are expecting, IIUC.

Here is how I would rearrange the dataframe:

```
merged = pd.concat([actual, predicted], keys=['actual', 'predicted'])
merged.index.names = ['category', 'index']
merged = merged.reset_index()
merged = pd.melt(merged, id_vars=['category', 'index'], value_vars=['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the ignore_index variable to false to preserve the index., e.g.

`df = df.melt(var_name=‘species’, value_name=‘height’, ignore_index = False)`